# Get first match in closing part of regex

Tags: regex

I must take string with regex who got string "[%" "%]" and any text or "" inside this. As example:

Input: `dsafsdfadsaffsdadsaffadsaf[%sadsad[%]%%]fdfsadfsad%]fsasdf`

Output: `[%sadsad[%]`

I already wrote expression - `\[%(.\n*)*%\]`, but it takes last of `%]`.

Output: `[%sadsad[%]%%]fdfsadfsad%]`

Did anyone know how get first of closing match?

Answer (score 1):

Put `.` and `\n` inside a capturing or non-capturing group delimited by a logical OR `|` operator, and make it as non-greedy.

```
\[%(.|\n)*?%\]
```

**OR**

You could do like the below.

```
\[%[\S\s]*?%\]
```

`[\S\s]*?` Matches any space or non-space character non-greedily.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such quickly and amazing answer!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
\[%[^\]]*%\]
```

You can try this to get string upto first closng `%]`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gX5qF3/5

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[%                       '['%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\]]*                   any character except: '\]' (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  %\]                       %']'
```