# Can't get first match (it's not about groups)

Tags: java, regex

I need to get this match `"Abcd"` for the string `"Abcd     23 p.  421 fd."` I wrote the pattern `"^(.*)\s+\d"` but it returns match with last digit like `"Abcd     23 p.  42"`. How to get first digit match?
*P.S. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27677040/4978865) solution but don't get it. How to use `|` subexpression to make pattern non-greedy.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `\D` - non-digit instead of `.` in your regex:

```
^(\D*)\s+\d
```

**EDIT:** since you only need first word (without digits and white space), you can use following, shorter regex:

```
^\w*
```

Comment: It reterns `"Abcd      2"`

Comment: And what should it return?

Comment: Just `"Abcd"` like I said.

Comment: And then you asked "How to get first digit match?". If you don't want digits, then remove `\d` - it's including the digit in result

Comment: And if you only want to take first word (no digits, no white space), regex is as simple as `^\w*`

Comment: Thank you for your help, just one final question. How to delete spaces after "Abcd" either?

Comment: No, it's not working. Reterns empty string. I solved it with `^(\D*)(?<!\s+)` pattern.